# What is wrong with my PLSQL dynamic code?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I'm learning PLSQL since 3 or 4 months, and now I'm practicing Dynamic SQL and I've write a simple procedure to update last name of an employee with Dynamic SQL. I don´t know what is the problem because when I call the procedure and insert the parameters I receive an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upd_emp_dyn(
  p_tname VARCHAR2,
  p_lname employees.last_name%TYPE,
  p_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE)
  IS
    v_dyn_stmt VARCHAR2(200) := 'UPDATE ' || p_tname ||
                                ' SET last_name = ' ||
                                p_lname || ' WHERE employee_id = ' ||
                                p_empid;
    v_confirm_stmt VARCHAR2(200) := 'SELECT * FROM ' || p_tname ||
                                    ' WHERE employee_id = ' ||
                                    p_empid;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dyn_stmt;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_confirm_stmt);
END upd_emp_dyn;
/
SHOW ERRORS;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  upd_emp_dyn('employees', 'Rooney', 120);
END;
/
```

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 2 del comando :
BEGIN
  upd_emp_dyn('employees', 'Rooney', 120);
END;
Informe de error -
ORA-00904: "ROONEY": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "HR.UPD_EMP_DYN", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 2
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: If you displayed your dynamic SQL statement in v_dyn_stmt  (e.g. using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE you would see why: `set lastname = Rooney...`

Comment: Shouldn't `IS` be `AS`?  Plus, what is the purpose of the lines with nothing but `/`?

Comment: Don't concatenate strings into your dynamic SQL. Use a placeholder and parameters. In your case the `update` is missing the required single quotes around the value of `p_lname`

Comment: @DanBracuk - agreed `AS` reads better than `IS` here, but both are valid.  The `/` (slash) is required by some tools, notably SQL*Plus, to terminate blocks of PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice (for both performance and security) is to use parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upd_emp_dyn(
  p_tname VARCHAR2,
  p_lname employees.last_name%TYPE,
  p_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE)
  IS
    v_dyn_stmt VARCHAR2(200) := 'UPDATE ' || p_tname ||
                                ' SET last_name = :1 WHERE employee_id = :2';
    v_confirm_stmt VARCHAR2(200) := 'SELECT * FROM ' || p_tname ||
                                    ' WHERE employee_id = :1';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dyn_stmt using p_lname, p_empid;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_confirm_stmt);
END upd_emp_dyn;
/
SHOW ERRORS;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  upd_emp_dyn('employees', 'Rooney', 120);
END;
/
```

For `select` statements use following:

```
declare
  result my_table%rowtype;
  id number := 123;
begin
  execute immediate 'select * from my_table where id = :1' into result using id;
end;
/
```

Also, it helps you to avoid typo errors (like which caused this question). And of course, you should avoid the use of dynamic SQL if it is possible to use static.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring table name as separate variable as parameter in your procedure..you can write a cursor for employees table & call that cursor in your dynamic query to print the output. So your dynamic sql in your proc will be more simple.